# VSTO Outlook: Start Outlook without an email account

Tags: outlook, command-line-interface, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I know that Outlook can be started without any email account configured. There are some methods as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-outlook-without-an-email-account-477a1fc3-4423-4156-bef4-67489edfdbef?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) and [here](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/using-outlook-without-an-email-account).
Some consists on pass below parameter to Outlook:

```
Outlook.exe /PIM <your profile name>
```

This creatse a new profile in Outlook without an email account.

Other methods consists on press 'Cancel' when Outlook ask for a profile. Unfortunatelly this method only seems to work in older Outlook versions <= 2016. I am using Office 365 for business App.

So right now I am debugging my VSTO Outlook Add-in from Visual Studio because I noticed that my VSTO Add-in is crashing when Outlook starts with no email account configured.

From Visual Studio I am trying somehow to start my VSTO Add-in by passing as parameter /PIM  or trying to start it without any email account but without success.

Is there any way that I can start my VSTO Outlook Add-in from Visual Studio and that allow me to specify Outlook parameters such as /PIM or without using an email account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the command line for VSTO add-ins in the following way:

[image: VSTO - start external program with parameters from VS]

This configuration works like a charm on my machine with Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200) 64-bit installed.

Note, the Outlook command line switch `/pim` creates a **new profile** each time you start a program. So, when you run the command line you need to pass a unique profile name to be created.

I'd suggest using the `/profile` command line switch when an empty profile was created using the `/pim` command which creates a new Mail Profile with the specified name but without an email account. The `/profile` command loads the specified profile. If your profile name contains a space, enclose the profile name in quotation marks ("").

Answer (score 1):

Of course - go to your VSTO addin properties, Debug | Command line arguments.

As for your particular problem, make sure your code does not unconditionally access `Namespace.CurrentUser`, which would be null if there is no mail account in the profile.

Comment: I put as arguments in VS: /PIM "no_account". My Add-in starts from VS, and then the New Profile popup appears asking me to create an account. If I cancel, then Vistual Studio debugging stops. If from control panel i go to mail and create a profile with no email account attached, then the profile is created successfully but when i start again the VSTO Add-in from VS and Outlook starts, Outlook ask me for the email account.

Comment: You can't create a new profile with the same name. Use the `/profile` command line switch  instead for debugging purposes.

Comment: And specifying command line arguments is not enough for VSTO add-ins, see my post for more information.

Comment: Instead of trying to create a new profile every time, create a profile in the Mail Control Panel cpl, and specify it on the command line when running using the `/profile` switch. Chances are your code unconditionally accesses `Namespace.CurrentUser`, which would be null if there is no mail account in the profile